# How to select environment by ip in Laravel

Tags: laravel-4, ip-address

I want laravel to set the environment to "local" when the visitor is from 127.0.0.1, however the Request object is not available yet in bootstrap/start. Is there any built-in way to do this, or am I going to have to directly access `$_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP']`?

Answer (score 2):

IP-based environment detection via $app->detectEnvironment() were removed recently. I believe it was in 4.1, because they were not very secure. A user can spoof their IP address and thus potentially access areas of the site you don't want them to access -- or get secure debug information, for example.

I know you asked for an IP solution, but the built-in method for detecting your environment should look like this:

```
$env = $app->detectEnvironment(array(
  'local' => array('MYHOSTNAME'),
));
```

If you have multiple systems/hostnames working from localhost, just add them to the array. This will keep things much more secure than trying to make IP addresses work.

Answer (score 0):

This sort of thing should work.

```
$env = $app->detectEnvironment(function() {
    if($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] == '127.0.0.1') { return 'local'; }
});
```

Swap out `REMOTE_ADDR` for `HTTP_CLIENT_IP` if that's how your infrastructure works.

If you want to use the Request object, you might be able to do it in an `App::before` filter, but I'm not certain if you can change the environment at runtime.